# Boot is slow and grub menu is ugly? Just dealt with a broken install.

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, updates, cups-lpd

So I was running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Think-pad Yoga 14. It was fantastic until one morning it broke. Boot got stuck on something like "Starting CUPS driver" Don't quite remember. Either way after frustration I re-installed Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu running on a 1tb HDD and Kali on a 16gb SSD. However, Ubuntu runs noticeably slower than before and takes much longer to boot (17 seconds) Any ideas? cause I don't have any. Re-post with any tests/outputs I should preform please :D

Comment: What do you mean the grub menu is ugly? And how does Kali perform?

Comment: I'm afraid it's unclear what you are asking. Was the Ubuntu running on the SSD before? Have you checked SMART status on the HDD? taked much longer to boot than Kali or than before?

Comment: A 17 second boot time isn't very long. And did you go to Ubuntu 14 or 15? That would be why it's slower. I don't really see the issue here. GRUB has never looked very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Of course Ubuntu takes longer to boot. By definition, an HDD is slower than an SSD. And even if you didn't have Ubuntu on an SSD before, newer versions of Ubuntu take slightly longer to boot compared to older versions. Just compare the boot times from MSDOS to Windows 10: the newer version is slower.

At 17 seconds for a boot time, you really don't have a problem, and certainly nothing to complain about.